# let $p$ be a polynomial. If $p(x)=p(x+1)$ for all real $x$, then prove that $p$ is constant.

Tags: polynomials

let $p$ be a polynomial. If $p(x)=p(x+1)$ for all real $x$, then prove that $p$ is constant.

I can't think of how to prove this. It seems almost trivial, I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many zeros does $p(x) - p(0)$ have?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340889/42969? See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340899/42969.

Comment: Notice the property is verified by the derivative $p'(x)=p'(x+1)$ in particular after $n-1$ derivations you get $n!a_nx+b$ and must have $a_n=0$ so the term of higher degree is obliterated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $k=p(0)$. What can you say about the number of solutions of the equation $p(x)=k$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is not constant. Then it has at least one root and since it is periodic it has infinitely many roots. A contradiction.